# How to commit offset in Camel Kafka when enable auto commit is false?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am using apache camel to integerate with my kafka messaging. Also i am using JAVA DSL to consume messages from kafka endpoint.

Using apache kafka API's its known how to commit consumer offsets with given properties toggling.

if i disbale auto commit in camel-kafka component how can i commit offsets in apcahe camel then?

I am using below endpoint to disable auto commit in Apache Camel

kafka.consumer.uri = kafka://{{kafka.host}}?zookeeperHost={{zookeeper.host}}&zookeeperPort={{zookeeper.port}}&groupId={{kafka.consumerGroupId}}&topic={{kafka.topic.transformer_t}}&{{kafka.uri.options}}
kafka.uri.options = autoCommitEnable=false

Is there any way to commit message offset manually now ?

Comment: see this issue got solved https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8085